# How to receive a rtp, rtcp or udp, from a stream of gstreamer, on video HTML5?

Tags: html, udp, gstreamer, rtp, rtcp

I'm trying to get a video stream RTP/RTCP using HTML5, the stream was generated by gstreamer. I used examples of gstreamer, so I can pass through RTP ports:5000, and RTCP:5001, and can receive streams using gstreamer. But using HTML5 could not receive them. So I tried to read a bit about HTML5 and saw that it can receive theora/ogg, webm/vp8, mp4/avc, and protocols may be, HTTP, RTP, RTCP, UDP, and others, but I could not use RTP, RTCP or UDP, HTTP only managed to receive. But I had a very satisfactory result using the VLC plugin for Mozilla Firefox, using the UDP protocol. I wonder if anyone has any tips, I do not want to use source files as src="/tmp/test.avi" needs to be a video stream that can be udp, RTP, RTCP. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to stream at low fps, you can use GStreamer to transcode your stream in MJPEG and stream it in TCP, and then use VLC to get this TCP stream and stream it to HTTP. It works very well (0.5 sec of latency), but if you decrease the fps (1 fps) VLC introduces a latency of around 11 sec.

Here are some test commands that should work out of the box, using the GStreamer videotestsrc :

- GStreamer :

  > gst-launch -v videotestsrc horizontal-speed=1 ! deinterlace ! videorate ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=15/1, width=256,
  >   height=144 ! jpegenc quality=20 ! multipartmux 
  >   boundary="--videoboundary" ! tcpserversink host=localhost port=3000
- VLC :

  > vlc -vvv -I rc tcp://localhost:3000 --sout
  >   '#standard{access=http{mime=multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--7b3cc56e5f51db803f790dad720ed50a},mux=mpjpeg,dst=localhost:8081}'
- then open a browser to `http://localhost:8081` (or create an HTML page with an img tag whose "src" attribute is `http://localhost:8081`)